# How to make entry into a integer?

Tags: python, tkinter

My Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

main_window = Tk()

# Labels
Label(main_window, text= "enter your name please enter your name").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(main_window, text= "Whats your age").grid(row=1, column=0)

# Text input
name = Entry(main_window,width=50, borderwidth=5)
name.grid(row=0,column=1 )
age = Entry(main_window,width=50, borderwidth=5)
age.grid(row=1,column=1)

# Safe gaurds
if age <= 0:
b1 = DISABLED
else:
    def on_click():
        print(f"my name is {name.get()}, and my age is {age}")
        #Button
        b1 = Button(main_window,text="click me", command=on_click).grid(row=2,column=1)

main_window.mainloop()
```

My problem is for this line "if age <= 0:" the variable can't be an event so how am I supposed to make an integer?

Thank You!

(Sorry if I have done something wrong, as this is my first time on StackOverFlow)

Comment: `if int(age)<= 0:`

Comment: To be clear: you want to base the code on the *text that has been entered into* the `Entry`, and treat that text as an integer? Okay, so that is two steps. Which one don't you know how to do? If it's the first one, you should try to read the documentation for Entry. If it's the second one, I can link you to an existing question instead.

Comment: Actually, I found duplicates for both parts of the question.

Comment: ok I will read the documentation for entry

Comment: @UlisesBussi: no, that's not correct in this specific case. `age` isn't a string, it's an object.

Comment: `if int(age.get) <= 0:`